# Select (max)+1 then insert in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to insert selected maximum value of queue row then +1 by j_id?

controller:

```
$id = array('j_jumlah' => ($this->input->post('jid'));
$this->mmeeting->add_q($id);
```

mmeting model:

```
function add_q($id){
        $query = $this->db->query('INSERT q_numb (Select_max(q_numb)+1)
                           SELECT j_id
                           FROM meeting
                           WHERE j_id = $id');
        }
```

Comment: why not just use an auto_incrementing id?

Comment: @MarcB auto increment the queue row value  by the j_id.., any idea?